# Add trailing slash if url contains keyword

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried several versions of trailing slash code but none of them are working for me. I want a trailing slash to be added only when url contains a keyword **news**, so

```
domain.com/news
domain.com/news/category/foo
domain.com/news/archive/august-2018
```

should trigger it to add a slash. I have this right now

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(news.*)$
RewriteRule ^/news(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using two separate rules, one for just `news` on it's own, and another for `news/categroy/foo`:

```
# direct news to news/
RewriteRule ^news$ news/ [L,R=301]

# if no trailing slash, direct news/* to news/*/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])$
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ news/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

These three rules result in:

```
http://www.example.com/news => http://www.example.com/news/
http://www.example.com/news/category/foo => http://www.example.com/news/category/foo/
http://www.example.com/news/archive/august-2018 => http://www.example.com/news/archive/august-2018/
```

You can test these rules using [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=722ac447-7878-558e-9105-a4a12413646b).

Comment: Apologies! I've updated my answer above to check for an already trailing slash :)

Comment: @VeeK Did this work as intended? Please accept my answer to help others if it did :)

Comment: I think its good but I'm getting an issue on localhost. Maybe you could help. `http://localhost/CCR/Website/news/cat/latest-news` goes to `http://localhost/E:/Documents/Projects/CCR/Website/news/cat/latest-news/`. I don't know why its adding the file path.

Comment: I'll upload it on the domain to test and let you know the results.

Comment: Its not working. Please try http://bwdmedia.in/ccr/news without end slash. It adds path to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below rule,

```
RewriteRule ^news$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
```